# Com CSS é possível preenche os "olhos" da Fonte? É possível preencher os "buracos" das letras A, O, P, etc?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, css-font-face

Eu estava querendo criar um título para usar nas sessões do meu site, mas queria que a fonte tivesse um efeito similar ao dessas imagens, Com os olhos preenchidos dando a impressão que a fonte tem o interior dos carácteres preenchido.

**Com CSS existe alguma forma prática para preencher o interior das letras?**
 
*Ou tenho que recorrer a outros recursos?*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**TESTE**

Fiz uns teste com `text-shadow` mas não cheguei a um resultado aplicável...

```css
h1 {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 
  8px 8px 0 red,
  16px 16px 0 red,
  22px 22px 0 red;
}
```

```html
<h1>AaBbDdOoPpQqR</h1>
```

Comment: Acho que o jeito valido seria criar uma camada por trás do texto preenchendo os buracos apenas

Comment: @GiovanniDias eu tentei de algumas formas, tipo "clipar" essa parte vermelha que está para fora do texto, mas não consegui...  Ou usar um `inset text-shadow`, mas tb não consegui...

Comment: veja essa ideia nesse post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30375406/to-add-bg-color-inside-the-space-of-an-single-letter-in-a-word,

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo É uma ideia, mas teria que ser feito uma classe para cada letra.. além disso não sei se separar um caractere com span manteria a semântica da palavra inteira...

Comment: pois é, mas foi a unica coisa que achei na net! São apenas 23 letras. Hahaha Alias, menos de 23 pq algumas não tem buracos

Comment: Vou resumir, qualquer resposta é algo bastante trabalhoso que por muitas vezes é desnecessário, o melhor é buscar uma fonte que siga exatamente este estilo que deseja, mas é apenas sugestão.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento acho que dessa vez à solução eh por ai mesmo no dafont.com já achei algumas e depois eh só gerar um Pack do font-face em algum site desses, tipo fontsquirrel.com

Comment: Com certeza muitas soluções podem e deveriam ser assim, certas coisas em CSS quebram o comportamento esperado, por exemplo o posicionamento do texto pode ser afetado e "quebrar" fazendo a "mascara" que usou para tapas os buracos fiquem em outro lugar, o controle fica bem mais dificil, lembro que a alguns anos estavam usando uma técnica de JS+Canvas+CSS para carregar fontes externas customizadas para websites, se o efeito de "blink" ainda é perceptível com `@fonte`, imagine com uma solução JS "mirabolante", tem hora que é melhor simplificar :)

Comment: hahaha fica triste não, fiz um gerador de letras sem buracos, veja http://kithomepage.com/sos/letras-sem-buracos.php

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo muito bom, ficou bem legal! Vc tem que construir a lista das classes antes né? E ele pega a string na lista de array e coloca a classe? Deve ter dado um "trabalhinho" rss, mas ficou legal parabéns!

Comment: Nada trabalhoso, veja `$novaFrase = str_split($frase);`  e  dai `foreach( $novaFrase as $value ){
    if( $value === 'a' ){
        $novaFraseConvertida .='<span class="fill-letter a">a</span>';
    }else if ( $value === 'A' ){ ......`

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo estou justamente na aula de arrays e loops, bem legal ver esse exemplo! valeu por compartilhar e se dar ao trabalho!

Comment: coloquei o codigo todo em um textarea pra vc ver, acessa o link de novo

Comment: Obs: sem o `<!DOCTYPE html>` não fica bom não

Comment: Valeu @LeoCaracciolo mais uma vez obrigado ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A melhor solução seria usar uma fonte que seja como você quer, porém ...

Uma forma gambiarrenta que se assemelha ao que quer é usar diversos `text-shadow` para criar a frase preenchida, usar `letter-spacing` para não sobrepor as letras e depois `transform: scaleX` para achatar

```css
h1 {
  color: transparent;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-shadow: red 0px 0px 0px, red 10px 0px 0px, red 20px 0px 0px, red 30px 0px 0px, red 40px 0px 0px;
  letter-spacing: 35px;
  transform: scaleX(0.30);
}
```

```html
<h1>AaBbDdOoPpQqR</h1>
```

Comment: Ficou até uma gambeta legal! Só é estranho quando tenta selecionar o texto rss, Mas valeu a tentativa. Acho que o ideal mesmo é usar uma fonte que já seja nesse estilo....

Comment: Essa "pergunta do dia" foi mais complicada, daqui a pouco posta ai uma solução genial

Comment: Dessa vez não tenho alternativa se não usa uma fonte que já venha nesse estilo

Answer (score 0):

O que eu tinha pensado foi exatamente o que esta no link do stack em inglês que te mandaram dei uma editada com suas letras. Algo como criar uma camada por baixo da letra e tampar apenas o buraco

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 100px;
  font-family: Verdana;
}

.fill-letter {
  position: relative;
}

.fill-letter:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
}

.A:after {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 30%;
  left: 33%;
  top: 30%;
  width: 35%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.a:after {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 20%;
  left: 32%;
  top: 60%;
  width: 35%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.B:after {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 50%;
  left: 33%;
  top: 30%;
  width: 38%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.b:after {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 33%;
  left: 33%;
  top: 45%;
  width: 38%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.D:after {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 45%;
  left: 33%;
  top: 30%;
  width: 40%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.d:after {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 35%;
  left: 30%;
  top: 40%;
  width: 40%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.O:after {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  top: 30%;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.o:after {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 35%;
  left: 25%;
  top: 40%;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.P:after {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 30%;
  left: 25%;
  top: 30%;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.p:after {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 30%;
  left: 25%;
  top: 45%;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.Q:after {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 45%;
  left: 25%;
  top: 30%;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.q:after {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 35%;
  left: 25%;
  top: 40%;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.R:after {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 30%;
  left: 25%;
  top: 30%;
  width: 42%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.e:after {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 20%;
  left: 25%;
  top: 40%;
  width: 45%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.g:after {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 35%;
  left: 25%;
  top: 40%;
  width: 45%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h1><span class="fill-letter A">A</span><span class="fill-letter a">a</span><span class="fill-letter B">B</span></span><span class="fill-letter b">b</span><span class="fill-letter D">D</span><span class="fill-letter d">d</span><span class="fill-letter O">O</span></span><span class="fill-letter o">o</span><span class="fill-letter P">P</span><span class="fill-letter p">p</span><span class="fill-letter Q">Q</span>
<span class="fill-letter q">q</span><span class="fill-letter R">R</span>
<span class="fill-letter e">e</span>
<span class="fill-letter g">g</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: faltam letras `e g q`  e letras acentuadas :D

Comment: usei a apenas as letras que ele colocou como exemplo :)

Comment: @GiovanniDias exemplo é exemplo. O ideal seria uma forma mais prática e sustentável, que mantenha a semântica e seja um pouco melhor de ser customizada etc... Acho que nesse caso em específico essa solução não seria viável, apesar de ser uma técnica que pode ser usada em outras situações...

Comment: A, O, P, etc? etc... todas as outras :)

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo quis dizer no código dele. Adicionei as outras letras mas como ele disse não é viável pro problema dele

Comment: Eu votei negativo na resposta, pois, ao meu ver, mesmo que produza visualmente o desejado a solução é inteiramente inviável. Além de ter que implementar todas as letras manualmente, fica preso à forma da fonte; isto é, se quiser mudar a fonte, terá que refazer o CSS. Nesse caso, ficaria muito mais simples e semântico editar os caracteres da fonte, criando uma personalizada, e utilizá-la. O interessante de usar CSS nesses casos é justamente a versatilidade e esta solução possui zero. Talvez se concordar comigo e adicionar as informações na resposta, irei rever meu voto.

Comment: Vou deixar a respostar ai para ajudar alguém a ver outra solução para o problema.